# ffmpeg -t frame duration

Tags: ffmpeg, video-editing

I want to cut a video using ffmpeg.
I want to use the -t option for that. And did already some testing to get a satisfying comand together.

All I wondering is how carefull I have to be with -t or -to and the given time. Lets say I want to cut the video on the frame that appears on timepoint 00:00:10.25. If it's 24Hz material the frame would be visible till 00:00:10.2917.

I wonder now whether there is some floor or roof method included in the -t option to guarantee that the frame will be depicted the very same time duration.

This is important for me, because I am afraid if it's not the case and I concatenate some videos together I might end up with micro stuttering.

Edit: To make a bit clearer what my question is about. I have two files that I want to concat together. Sadly part one has some seconds black at the end part two in the beginning.The merging I want to do in mkvtoolnix gui together with tagging of selected streams.

For that I do:

[code]
mkvextract attachments title_t00.mkv 1

ffmpeg -i title_t00.mkv -attach cover.jpg -map_metadata 0 -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a -map 0:s -c:a copy -c:s copy -c:v copy -metadata:s:t:0 mimetype=image/jpg -metadata:s:t:0 filename=cover.jpg -t 01:45:38.291 final-1.mkv

ffmpeg -i title_t01.mkv -attach cover.jpg -map_metadata 0 -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a -map 0:s -c:a copy -c:s copy -c:v copy -metadata:s:t:0 mimetype=image/jpg -metadata:s:t:0 filename=cover.jpg -ss 1.67 final-2.mkv
[/code]

I tried different cuts and watched the samples in mpv with single frame steps. Since mpv closes on the last frame I already figured out that I was off by one frame with that method.

But no after merging the two files I have no black frames left and I am not missing any frame, but the cut scene is sadly not smooth. Last frame is depicted longer.

I wonder if it depends on the exact time i hand over with -t. So if I enter a time between two frames that last frame is depicted shorter. However doing several tests with different times and looking at the duration in mkvinfo it seemed that there is indeed some floor method.

Comment: Please post your commands to your question as examples.